# Python create column of repeated values that matches length of dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, repeat

I need to create a column that repeats an initial value 32 times, then increases it by 1 and repeats 32 times, etc.. until it is the length of my original dataframe.

I tried doing the following (and other minor variants):

```
timestamps = [1506447570]
i = 0
k = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    timestamps.append(timestamps[i])
    k+=1
    i+= 1
    if k >31:
        timestamps.append(timestamps[i]+1)
        k =0
```

This is what it should look like for the first 2 repetitions:

```
timestamps = [
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447570,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571,
1506447571]
```

So it should continue repeating this pattern until it is the length of the dataframe. The values are unix timestamps and the data is collected at 32HZ so I'm just trying to make a simple timestamps column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `len` on `df.index` to get the length of your dataframe. From there, you can iterate over a range on that length and use division and [`floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) to change the numbers.

```
from math import floor
val = 1506447570

df['stamps'] = [val + floor(i / 32) for i in range(len(df.index))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this ago :)

```
acc = 2
seedStamp = 1506447570
timeStamps = []

for i in range(acc):
  for k in range(33):
    timeStamps.append(seedStamp)
    if k >31:
      seedStamp += 1
      timeStamps.append(seedStamp)

print('--')

for i in timeStamps:
  print(i)
```

Comment: This is close, but my dataframe is length 145849, and this gives me a timeStamps length of 4958866, and it repeats 33 times instead of 32